# Angularjs convert & to &amp;

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my angular js code.

```
$scope.getEventSeconds = function(){
    $http.get('myfile.php', {
    params: {
        'action': 'get_datas'
    }
 }).success(function(data){
        $scope.list = data;
        $scope.currentPage = 1; //current page
        $scope.entryLimit = 10; //max no of items to display in a page
        $scope.filteredItems = $scope.list.length; //Initially for no filter  
        $scope.totalItems = $scope.list.length;
    });
}
```

This is working find return all data but it convert url & to & like.

`http://example.com?id=1&name=myname` this is url store into database.

it convert url like.

`http://example.com?id=1&amp;name=myname`  it display like.

Comment: what's the different in both example urls /

Comment: sorry now check i edit my question thank you.

Comment: it's still unclear that what is your url variable...

Comment: check both url i pass array in data. $scope.list = data. that is i pass all data into data variable but it convert url & to &amp; so that when i try to run that url is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly from where your url is coming but I suppose your could do something like this:

```
var url = 'http://example.com?id=1&amp;name=myname'
url = url.replace(/&amp;/g, "&")
```

I hope this can help you, if not thanks for giving more information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing all of your urls are store within the 'data' returned in the ajax response. And you have urls stored in the databases and was escaped. You can restore the urls by unescaping them.

```
$scope.list = data.replace(/&amp;/g, "&");
```

This is however dangerous and should only be done as a filter when you display the url.